# Unable to start debugging on the web server after installing SharePoint

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, iis-7, sharepoint-2010

Visual studio 2010 was debugging fine on Win 7 , 64-bit machine. after installing sharepoint foundation 2010. SP site r working fine. but mvc, aspnet projects showing follwoing error

Unable to start debugging on the web server. the web server cound lnot find the requested resource.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When SharePoint is installed the default web site in IIS is replaced by the SharePoint default site. Create a whole new website (and also an application pool preferrably) for yourself in IIS and deploy your code there and try debugging it. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

From my past experience you cannot use an MVC template on a sharepoint environment (i.e. sharepoint iis site)

There are a few add-ons and customizations you can do, but their quite tedious.